# Does anyone know why CAS login can just stop working?

Tags: php, cas

I use CAS (php) for my app, and it was working perfect untill today. And I don't know why it stops working all of a sudden?

It shows that it breaks here when it redirects to:
http://www.example.se/j_spring_cas_security_check?ticket=ST-1370159-UlTutdqYpjEKYiT3DEev-cas
and then gives 404 Error.

But it actually logs me in, I mean when I click back to my app's login page after, I'm already logged in!

Any similar experience?